# fputs vs fwrite

Tags: php

По одним источникам fputs является алиасом fwrite. По другим - только fwrite возвращает количество записанных байтов. Кому верить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Верить можно только [офф. документации](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputs.php) или исходникам PHP. :)

> fputs — Alias of fwrite()

Comment: Это я читал. Увы, иногда там некоторые малоиспользуемые тонкости не указаны. =(